# pycparser ParseError

Tags: python, c, parsing, pycparser

I am trying to creat AST usinfg pyCparser,
The following error printed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Work\RE\Tools\VarsExporter\BuildExportedDb.py", line 1076, in 
main()
File "C:\Work\RE\Tools\VarsExporter\BuildExportedDb.py", line 1032, in main
ast = parse_file(i_file)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycparser_init_.py", line 93, in 
parse_file
return parser.parse(text, filename)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycparser\c_parser.py", line 152, in 
parse
debug=debuglevel)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycparser\ply\yacc.py", line 331, in 
parse
return self.parseopt_notrack(input, lexer, debug, tracking, tokenfunc)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycparser\ply\yacc.py", line 1199, in 
parseopt_notrack
tok = call_errorfunc(self.errorfunc, errtoken, self)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycparser\ply\yacc.py", line 193, in 
call_errorfunc
r = errorfunc(token)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycparser\c_parser.py", line 1761, in 
p_error
column=self.clex.find_tok_column(p)))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycparser\plyparser.py", line 67, in _ 
parse_error
raise ParseError("%s: %s" % (coord, msg))
ParseError: Objectffly\SerDb.i:43:18: before: __loff_t
```

What causes the above issue? How Can I handle it?
Any suggestions how can I debug it, and find out what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From pyCparser git FAQ:

> C code almost always #includes various header files from the standard C library, like stdio.h. While (with some effort) pycparser can be made to parse the standard headers from any C compiler, it's much simpler to use the provided "fake" standard includes in utils/fake_libc_include. These are standard C header files that contain only the bare necessities to allow valid parsing of the files that use them.

To solve the issue I have successfully used the method described [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/on-parsing-c-type-declarations-and-fake-headers/).